# carriage return

Tags: c#, html, sql, carriage-return

Using C# I have a WPF text box which accepts carriage returns. It saves into the SQL database as a carriage return (I have checked the ASCII on this) but when the application pulls it from the database and into a string and then prints it using HTML with no carriage return. How can I get the string to recognize the carriage return?

Comment: Check the HTML source.  I imagine the carriage return is there.  However, web browsers don't show a line break on a carriage return.  You'd need to replace it with HTML markup instead.

Comment: @SO community, this is this guys first question. **Hostile much?** Give him some feedback. A downvote without feedback helps no one...especially a first-timer.

Comment: I think this question is actually well written. It describes the exact problem. Not all questions need to have example code, it is clear from the information provided that the OP has tried something already and is only a step away from success. The only gripe I would say is valid is that this question has likely been answered before... so could be a duplicate

Comment: Those downvoters and close voters should cool down, +1

Comment: Just to give you an idea how best ask questions have a quick read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @musefan, totally agree. Thanks for taking the time to answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML doesn't display new lines based on carriage return, it uses specific markup: `<br/>`

Quick fix would be to convert all your new lines before rendering it as html...

```
string html = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
```

Comment: @user3801724: If my answer has solved your issue consider marking it as the accepted answer. That helps build both our reputation, and at your early stage you will benefit much more than I will by increasing your rep.